# How to install third-party modules on python3

Tags: python

There are several versions of python on my mac OS X system.
I just installed beautiful soup4 on python2.7.6, but how can I install the same module on the version 3.4.3?

Comment: That depends on how you installed those Python versions. Most likely there's a `pip3` command available for Python 3, if pip is your preferred installation method.

Comment: If you have both Python2 and Python3 version installed you can use `pip install --target=required_path required_package` to specify where exactly to save module: to Python2 `site-packages` folder or Python3... Just change `required_path` with your actual path to modules and `required_package` with `beautifulsoup4`

Answer (score 1):

From the [BeautifulSoup Official Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup):

> Beautiful Soup 4 is published through PyPi, so if you can’t install it
>   with the system packager, you can install it with easy_install or pip.
>   The package name is beautifulsoup4, and the same package works on
>   Python 2 and Python 3.
>
> ```
> $ easy_install beautifulsoup4
>
> $ pip install beautifulsoup4
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You should always use a virtualenv. For each project, install the requirements you need inside that project's own virtualenv.